# How to convert value hashes from a stored procedure into an array of Sequel model instances or dataset

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

A stored procedure returns an array of rows (`SETOF`) from a table called `ACCOUNTS` with its associated Sequel model `Account`:

```
[1] pry(#<Psql::CalculateMasterBalancesTest>)> DB.select(Sequel.lit('*')).from{ |o| Sequel.function(:get_master_accounts, DB.row_type(:accounts, @accounts['A/1/1'].values)) }.all
=> [{:id=>1651, :parent_id=>1649, :ban=>nil, :risk=>nil, :custom_attributes=>nil, :created_at=>2017-05-17 19:33:09 +0200, :updated_at=>2017-05-17 19:33:09 +0200},
 {:id=>1649, :parent_id=>1647, :ban=>nil, :risk=>nil, :custom_attributes=>nil, :created_at=>2017-05-17 19:33:09 +0200, :updated_at=>2017-05-17 19:33:09 +0200},
 {:id=>1647, :parent_id=>nil, :ban=>"A Master", :risk=>nil, :custom_attributes=>nil, :created_at=>2017-05-17 19:33:09 +0200, :updated_at=>2017-05-17 19:33:09 +0200}]
```

To make this play nice with the rest of the application I would like to instantiate this array of value hashes into an array of `Account` model instances.

If I just add `.map{|hash| Account.new(hash)}` to the end of the previous expression I get a

```
Sequel::MassAssignmentRestriction: id is a restricted primary key
```

error.

If I bully through this and manually set the ID column I'm guessing there's good chances that something will bite me somewhere (in some weird edge case if possible) due to `persisted?` logic somewhere in Sequel (I'm just guessing, this is what happens with ActiveRecord and it seems a common design issue),

Is there an idiomatic way of handling this in Sequel?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes writing a question gives you an answer:

```
Account.from{ |o| Sequel.function(:get_ancestry, DB.row_type(:accounts, @accounts['A/1/1'].values)) }.all
```

works.

---

Actually, this works really, really, really nice, because it behaves like any dataset would, you can join it, "where" it, sort it etc and everything behaves really really nicely.

```
  DB.register_row_type(:accounts)

  def ancestry_dataset
    Account.from do |o|
      Sequel.function(:get_ancestry, DB.row_type(:accounts, values))
    end
  end
```

and then:

```
def test_me
  acc = @accounts['A/1/1']
  pd = acc.ancestry_dataset

  assert pd.is_a?(Sequel::Postgres::Dataset), 'expected a postgres dataset'

  assert_equal 2, pd.count, 'count returned funny'
  assert_equal 2, pd.all.count, 'all.count returned funny'

  assert_equal 1, pd.where(parent_id: nil).count, 'where(...).count returned funny'
  assert_equal 1, pd.where(parent_id: nil).all.count, 'where(...).all.count returned funny'

  assert_equal [:id], pd.select(:id).first.keys, 'when I restrict the select statement columns, the keys are funny'
end
```

It works nicely without hickups and is a great powertool for handling hierarchical data.

For future reference, the `get_ancestry` function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ancestry(_acct Accounts)
  RETURNS SETOF Accounts AS $$

DECLARE
  cur_acct Accounts%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  -- we start from the parent of _acct
  SELECT INTO cur_acct *
  FROM Accounts
  WHERE id = _acct.parent_id;

  WHILE (cur_acct.id IS NOT NULL) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'get_ancestry: returning %', cur_acct.id;
    RETURN NEXT cur_acct;

    SELECT INTO cur_acct *
    FROM Accounts
    WHERE id = cur_acct.parent_id;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: By default Sequel will select `*` so `.select(Sequel.lit('*'))` is redundant. Try `Account.dataset.sql` and look at the output.  In general the query looks very awkward. I'd recommend asking on the Sequel IRC channel.

Answer (score 0):

"id is a restricted primary key" is because you're passing in the `:id` of the record.

Delete `:id` from the value before trying to instantiate a new Account.

```
.select(Sequel.lit('*'))
```

shouldn't be necessary. Sequel automatically selects `*`:

```
require 'json'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end
items = DB[:items]
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100)

class Item < Sequel::Model(:items)
end

Item.dataset.sql
# => "SELECT * FROM `items`"
```

Comment: Indeed, but if I just delete the ID when I instantiate, then Sequel will think I have a new record when I use the resulting Sequel::Model object. I had to find a way so that Sequel understands that we're dealing with something that already exists, so it can be joined, updated, etc and generally managed without any special handling.